# Get DIV contents with Java Swing

Tags: java, html, swing, parsing, htmleditorkit

I'm trying to get DIV contents from previously fetched HTML document. I'm using Java Swing.

```
final java.io.Reader stringReader = new StringReader(html);
final HTMLEditorKit htmlKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
final HTMLDocument htmlDoc = (HTMLDocument) htmlKit.createDefaultDocument();
final HTMLEditorKit.Parser parser = new ParserDelegator();
parser.parse(stringReader, htmlDoc.getReader(0), true);
final javax.swing.text.Element el = htmlDoc.getElement("id");
```

This code should get a DIV with ID of "id" that I have inside html.
But what next? How to get the contents of div? Been searching it all around but only thing I found is how to get attribute value, not the Element contents.

Should I move to jsoup? I would rather use Java native, but so far I'm stuck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> not the Element contents.

Try something like:

```
int start = el.getStartOffset();
int end = el.getEndOffset();
String text = htmlDoc.getText(start, end - start);
```